# cin.get() broke after adding stat() check

Tags: c++, cin, stat

So I wanted to add a stat() check on a dir. After compiling it started tossing some really strange stuff. Heres what I got:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <sys/stat.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;
struct stat sb;

int main()
{
    cout<<" \n";
    cout<<"                 Account Progam\n"
    cout<<" \n";
    cout<<"             Created by: Illyduss\n";
    cout<<"                      2015\n";
    cout<<" \n";
    cout<<" \n";
    cout<<" \n";
    std::string account;
    cout<<"Do you already have an account? \n";
    cout<<"Type 'NEW' to create an account or enter your account name.\n";
    cout<<"Account Name: ";
    cin>> account;
    cin.ignore();
    string str1(account);
    to_upper(account);
    if (account == "NEW"){

        ...Some if checking here and junk...

        ...And then what was recently added the bugs my cin.get()...

    else {
        cout<< "Welcome back, '" << account << "'!\n";
        struct stat sb;
        if (stat("/home/user/Account Program/accounts",&sb) == 0 && S_ISDIR(sb.st_mode)){
            cout<<"Please enter your password: ";
        }
        else {
            cout<< "There is no account by that name, please type NEW to create a new account.\n";
        }
        }
    }
    cin.get();
}
```

I added cin.get() to keep the terminal open after it's run so I can see whats going on, but I believe it is conflicting with my dir check because it was running just fine until I added that check in to see if an account was already made before attempting to open the account dir.

Specifically I am getting these errors:

```
intro.cpp:112:2: error: ‘cin’ does not name a type
  cin.get();
  ^
intro.cpp:113:1: error: expected declaration before ‘}’ token
 }
 ^
user@computer:~/Account Program$ g++ intro.cpp
intro.cpp:112:2: error: ‘cin’ does not name a type
  cin.get();
  ^
intro.cpp:113:1: error: expected declaration before ‘}’ token
 }
 ^
```

As well it is tossing me an error on the } used to close out int main() like once it gets to the dir check it tosses me out of my int main()? Am I not closing off the stat() correctly?

Comment: I suspect you've got mismatched braces... why are there two after the `cout << "There is no account by that name"`?

Comment: Facepalm all the way, thanks. Looks like its always passing True though so even when a dir doesn't exist it prompts for password instead of going to else. Hmm...

Comment: *"even when a dir doesn't exist it prompts"* - that's very unlikely; you do realise you're checking that the `/home/user/Account Program/accounts` exists, not that it contains a file or subdirectory with a name matching whatever's in `account`...?

Comment: OMG! double facepalm.

Comment: no worries.  Might as well close the question though - nothing here will help future readers....

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <sys/stat.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;
struct stat sb;

int main()
{
    cout<<" \n";
    cout<<"                 Account Progam\n"
    cout<<" \n";
    cout<<"             Created by: Illyduss\n";
    cout<<"                      2015\n";
    cout<<" \n";
    cout<<" \n";
    cout<<" \n";
    std::string account;
    cout<<"Do you already have an account? \n";
    cout<<"Type 'NEW' to create an account or enter your account name.\n";
    cout<<"Account Name: ";
    cin>> account;
    cin.ignore();
    string str1(account);
    to_upper(account);
    if (account == "NEW"){

        ...Some if checking here and junk...

        ...And then what was recently added the bugs my cin.get()...

    else {
        cout<< "Welcome back, '" << account << "'!\n";
        struct stat sb;
        if (stat(("/home/user/Account Program/accounts/"+account).c_str(),&sb) == 0 && S_ISDIR(sb.st_mode)){
            cout<<"Please enter your password: ";
        }
        else {
            cout<< "There is no account by that name, please type NEW to create a new account.\n";
        }
    }
    cin.get();
}
```

I had an extra } after the last else and needed to add the child dir that was being checked via like so ("/home/user/Account Program/accounts/"+account).c_str().